# Pass the file to a different method

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to complete an app, which takes a .txt file and adds it to the database.

This is used mostly to keep the available items, within a warehouse, and the issue is when an item already exists, the app needs to read thru the lines, and update the record that is already in the database.

To add the item, (if it's a new entry) that's already completed, and checked the database to see if the item exists, which is being added normally.

But to update, it's where I'm trying to figure out possible ways to do it, and would appreciate any input on this:

Let me share the exact code in use:

Here we check if the item exists already, and the comparison is based on boolean, but from what I understand, we need also the integer value of the entry this method finds.

```vb
If CheckItemsIfExists(file.Rows(0).Item(1)) = True Then
    MsgBox("Item with Number: " & & " Found, updating Database")
    UpdateDB()
End If
```

```vb
Private Function CheckItemsIfExists(dbEntry As String) As Boolean
    Dim dummyVar As recordFind = ' It's the service which connects to check the DB, not related with the issue.
    Dim query = String.Format("SELECT entry FROM table WHERE code= '" + dbEntry + "'")
    dummyVar.DoQuery(query)
    Dim entryCount = dummyVar.entryCount

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dummyVar)
    dummyVar = Nothing
    GC.Collect()

    If entryCount = 0 Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return "need to return the integer found, in order to pass it for the update method?"
    End If
End Function
```

In total there's 3 methods which take place:

1. AddTheItemtoDB
2. CheckIfItemExists
3. UpdateDB (if exists, otherwise create a new entry)

For the 1st, the app adds the item to the DB, if not found.
For the 2nd, we check based on true or false if the item exists, but if true-->updateDB, there's no integer value passed on the updateDB method (the entry from the DB), and that's the core of the issue.

Comment: VBA or VB.Net???

Comment: First, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER use non parametrized SQL querys, second, you can use a stored procedure or even a MERGE query and do this with only function, but that is a SQL question

Comment: @FunThomas vb.net, I removed the vba flag, thank you.

Comment: If you have to use `GC.Collect()` after querying a database, it seems to me that something is very wrong in how it is done. Is there a reason for calling the garbage collector?

Comment: Adding to @AndrewMorton, you may benefit by declaring this `recordFind` class as `IDisposable`, and wrap access to your database in a `Using` block. Inside the Dispose method you release your resources, and I guess you have some *unmanaged* things to destroy - do that in the correct way in `Dispose`.